# Protobuf-net v2 Custom List object error

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a List as defined below with protobuf-net v2, and on deserialize I am getting the following exception.

> Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred

In the example below I am using the WithLengthPrefix calls because this is actually going over a network stream, but the problem is reproducible either way.

```
var mStream = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(mStream, testList, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var nOrders = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix
                  <List<TestObj>>(mStream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
```

With RiskOrder as defined below

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestObj
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Key{ get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Val{ get; set; }
}
```

It appears this could be related to the bug posted at [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=168), but as it has not been confirmed I thought I'd see if anyone else has run into this / has a work around.

Update
I forgot to mention this problem only seems to occur if the list has entries in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe r403 fixed this bug, as I updated to the latest source as opposed to the v2 beta, and it appears to be fixed.